# How do I use the WHERE LIKE SQL clause?

Tags: sql, c

```
sprintf(query, "SELECT username, msg, ts, lat, lon FROM tweet WHERE msg LIKE '%'%s'%' ORDER BY ts DESC", keyword);
```

The way I did it, is giving me errors. How am I supposed to format the '%keyword%' into SQL using printf?

Comment: Whatever you are doing, if possible use parametric queries instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If my understanding SQL Query statements is correct, when the value of `keyword` is `NBA`, you want the query string to look like:

```
"SELECT username, msg, ts, lat, lon FROM tweet WHERE msg LIKE '%NBA%' ORDER BY ts DESC"
```

In that case, the format of the `sprintf` statement needs to be:

```
"SELECT username, msg, ts, lat, lon FROM tweet WHERE msg LIKE '%%%s%%' ORDER BY ts DESC"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to quote the percent sign by doubling it `%%`

```
sprintf(query, "SELECT username, msg, ts, lat, lon FROM tweet WHERE msg LIKE '%%%s%%' ORDER BY ts DESC", keyword);
                                                                              ^^  ^^
```

**As noted**: concatenating strings is error prone and may be subject to SQL injection attacks. Use parameterised queries instead.

Comment: The extra apostrophes wrapping the %s will result in invalid sql.

Comment: Thanks. I copied from original and they slipped through.